# 'int' object is not callable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I try running this program (code below) it returns a `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`

Code:

```
import random
import math

def var():
    strength = 10
    skill = 10
    dice4 = 0
    dice12 = 0

    character_name = str(input("Please enter your characters name: "))
    skill(strength, skill, dice4, dice12, character_name)

def skill(strength, skill, dice4, dice12, character_name):

    print(character_name + "'s attributes are being generated! ... ")

    dice4, dice12 = random.randrange(1,4), random.randrange(1,12) 

    dice_score = dice12/dice4
    dice_score = math.floor(dice_score)
    skill = skill + dicescore

    strength(strength, skill, dice4, dice12, character_name)

def strength(strength, skill, dice4, dice12, character_name):
    dice4, dice12 = random.randrange(1,4), random.randrange(1,12) 

    dice_score = dice12/dice4
    dice_score = math.floor(dice_score)
    strength = strength + dicescore
    file(strength, skill, dice4, dice12, character_name)

def file(strength, skill, dice4, dice12, character_name):
    file = open("N:\Controlled Assessment - Ryan Harper\Task Two\attributes.txt", w)
    file.writelines(character_name + " - Strength = " + str(strength) + ", Skill = " + str(skill))

var()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "N:\Controlled Assessment - Ryan Harper\Task Two\task 2 v2.py", line 37, in <module>
    var()
  File "N:\Controlled Assessment - Ryan Harper\Task Two\task 2 v2.py", line 11, in var
    skill(strength, skill, dice4, dice12, character_name)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 3):

You should not have a variable and a function both called `skill`.

Same thing for `strength`.

This really confuse the interpreter and yourself.

Give them other fansy names instread. :)

Answer (score 2):

In the function `var`, `skill` is a local name bound to an integer, which shadows the global function `skill()`. Use a different name for one of them.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line:

skill(strength, skill, dice4, dice12, character_name)

You call skill as a function but it is a number which is defined a few lines before this line.